# Moving between terminals at Heathrow to visit a lounge

Tags: airports, lhr, lounges

We are traveling from Heathrow Airport Terminal 2. We would like to visit a lounge in Terminal 1 or 3 before we fly. Is it possible to check into T2 and then move between terminals before we fly?

Answer (score 5):

Normally, it is not possible to move freely between terminals at Heathrow, unless you [book a shopping transfer](http://www.heathrowairport.com/shop,-eat,-relax-and-enjoy/personal-shopper). You need to check in and clear security in your departure terminal, and then otherwise need to stay there. On arrival, if you're transferring to another terminal, you do that before clearing security, so you can't enter the other terminal

However... Terminals 1 and 2 are special. They currently share quite a few facilities, including sharing a pier. That will continue for another year or so, until they finally close down what's left of Terminal 1. (Terminal 2 will then be expanded over the site of the current Terminal 1)

You can find the details on how to walk between the two in [this thread on FlyerTalk](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/u-k-ireland/1595196-t1-t2-airside-connection-heathrow.html), expect to allow 10-15 minutes. (You basically need to walk to the shared pier, then follow the signs to whichever main terminal you want to be in)

That said, the lounges in Terminal 2 are brand new and miles miles better than anything in Terminal 1, so you'd really be much better staying in T2 and visiting the lounges there!

Answer (score -1):

The answer is yes. Terminals 1, 2 and three are 5-10 minutes walking from each other. There is a good navigation system and signing everywhere as well. So it should not be a problem for you to walk to the lounge in a different terminal.